# Paralleling Insertion Sort, Naive Attempt, Failed Attempt With pthreads, Threads Not Sorted In Parallel, But Work Fine With Serial

Tags: c++, multithreading, sorting, parallel-processing, pthreads

## Context

Hello!

I was attempting to play around with pthreads, and decided to implement Insertion Sort to see the performance differences, but I'm stuck with a weird error and I'm not sure where to go or what problem I'm really running into.

## Steps

For context, what I did for paralleling Insertion Sort is as follows,

1. Make a function to solely contain it there
2. Send to that function a struct container, i) A pointer to the array itself, ii) The array
   size,
3. Got the number of cores ( let's called this `numberOfCores` via a func on my machine ( yes, the output is correct, I have 4 cores )
4. Created `numberOfCores` pthread_t objects
5. Keeping in mind that it's not necessary that the last thread will deal with an array that contains equal number of elements ( trying to divide the balance to the threads accordingly )
6. So I create a 2D matrix, with rows == `numberOfCores - 1`, and cols == `floor(sizeOfArray / numberOfCores)`, I've checked again and again with different test inputs, these are correctly assigned,
7. Made a `lastArray` array, with size, `lastArraySize = (sizeOfCompleteArray / numberOfCores) + (sizeOfCompleteArray % numberOfCores)`
8. I then split the original array into the `subArrays`, the 2D matrix
9. Then I split the last section of the array for `lastArray`,
10. I then packed the respective arrays and their sizes, and assigned the threads to run the simple `insertionSort` function, sending in their respective `packed` data. My plan is to `merge` the different arrays after they've been sorted by each individual thread. I know it's 100% possible to write a more efficient code base, but this is just something small, I don't want to spend too much on this. Please see the below code for line by line examination.
11. Then I used `pthread_join` to get the `numberOfCores` arrays as sorted
12. Then I checked if each is sorted.

## Problems

Here is what the problems arise,

1. If I sort the above arrays sequentially, using a loop, starting from step 9 ( mentioned above ), all of the arrays do get sorted as expected. No problems here
2. However, If I try my parallel version, I'm met with unexpected results. Sometimes 2 are sorted, sometimes only 1, sometimes 3, but never 4. Why it keeps giving me unreliable results is beyond me right now.
3. Array[0] is ALWAYS unsorted. I have no idea why. It does get sorted when I use the serial method described above, but never with the parallel method.

## Code

```cpp
// def for InsertionSortPacking, mentioned below 
struct InsertionSortPacking
{
    ull *Array;       // Pointer to the array
    size_t ArraySize; // Size of the array
};

static inline void *
pthread_insertionSort(void *arrayMetaDataToUnpack) // arrayMetaDataToUnpack contains the pointer used to pass the data to the func
{
    // UNPACKING START
    ull *_Array = ((InsertionSortPacking *)arrayMetaDataToUnpack)->Array;
    size_t sizeOfArray = ((InsertionSortPacking *)arrayMetaDataToUnpack)->ArraySize;
    // UNPACKING END

    // Compulsory use of reinterpret_cast to keep everything consistent
    ull *__tempArray = reinterpret_cast<ull *>(_Array);

    // Custom func to get the number of cores on machine
    int numberOfCores = getNumCores();
    std::cout << "Number of cores detected: " << numberOfCores << ".\n";

    // Step 1, create vars
    pthread_t threads[numberOfCores];              // all threads must run, step 4
    int rows = numberOfCores - 1;                  // ... but not every thread might be bound to have equal job ( equal sub array sizes ), step 5
    int cols = floor(sizeOfArray / numberOfCores); // the most evenly contained size possible, step 6
    ull subArrays[rows][cols]{0u};                 // the {} initializes everything for me, step 6

    // step 7
    int lastArraySize = (sizeOfArray / numberOfCores) + (sizeOfArray % numberOfCores);
    ull lastArray[lastArraySize];

    // step 8
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
            subArrays[i][j] = __tempArray[i * numberOfCores + j];

    // step 9
    for (int i = 0, j = cols * rows + 1;
         i < lastArraySize and j < sizeOfArray;
         ++i, ++j)
        lastArray[i] = __tempArray[j];

    // EXTRA, just for clarification. Individually, all work fine
    // getTimeForTemplate just prints out some logs, takes in the
    // the function pointer to the function I want to use, the array, I want to sort, the size, and a text to print
    // for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    //     getTimeForTemplate(insertionSort, subArrays[i], cols, "insertion sort - serial, subArray[" + std::to_string(i) + std::string("]"));
    // getTimeForTemplate(insertionSort, lastArray, lastArraySize, "insertion sort - serial, lastArray");

    // step 10
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        InsertionSortPacking __tempPacking{};

        if (i == rows) // Step 3.1, for the lastArray
        {
            __tempPacking.Array = (ull *)lastArray;
            __tempPacking.ArraySize = lastArraySize;
        }
        else // Step 3.2, for the remaining arrays
        {
            __tempPacking.Array = (ull *)subArrays[i];
            __tempPacking.ArraySize = cols;
        }

        int __rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], nullptr, insertionSort, (void *)&__tempPacking);
        if (__rc)
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Unable to create thread, rc " << __rc << " i, " << i << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // step 11, joining the pthreads, regardless of array size
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        int __rc = pthread_join(threads[i], nullptr);
        if (__rc)
        {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Unable to join thread, rc " << __rc << " i, " << i << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // Step 12, checking if all the jobs have completed the sorting
    for (int i = 0; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
        InsertionSortPacking __tempPacking{};

        if (i == rows) // Step 3.1, for the lastArray
        {
            __tempPacking.Array = (ull *)lastArray;
            __tempPacking.ArraySize = lastArraySize;

            if (isSorted(&__tempPacking) == -1) // Sorting succeeded if -1 returned
                std::cout << "Sorting succeeded for lastArrray\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Sorting failed for lastArray\n";
        }
        else // Step 3.2, for the remaining arrays
        {
            __tempPacking.Array = (ull *)subArrays[i];
            __tempPacking.ArraySize = cols;

            if (isSorted(&__tempPacking) == -1) // Sorting succeeded if -1 returned
                std::cout << "Sorting succeeded for subArray[" << i << "]\n";
            else
                std::cout << "Sorting failed for subArray[" << i << "]\n";
        }
    }

    ...
    // further code for merging and whatnot

    return sortedArray;
```

And the command that I'm using to compile and run,

```
g++ -std=gnu++17 -std=c++17 -O2 insertion.cpp -o insertion -lpthread && ./insertion > log.log
```

Here are some logs from the complete program, https://gist.github.com/Rubix982/d0bbdabc2d8a1fc531e9104f7172dbfe

## What problems do I have and why can't I fix them?

1. This does not seem like a race condition at all. Each array is different and independent in memory. No two threads access a different thread anywhere in the sequence
2. ... It could be that threads are sometimes joined when they are partially sorted - can that happen?
3. I'm not running more threads than my machine can handle ( 4 cores  for sure )
4. I do not understand where to and how to debug why sometimes 1 thread fails, or why 3 threads fail the other time
5. I do not see the need for mutex locks here at all. No race conditions, but maybe I'm thinking about this from the wrong angle
6. I tried using `sleep()` to make sure the threads get their work done in due time BEFORE joining them together, but to no avail.

## Conclusion

Any help would be appreciated! Please let me know where I might be making an error and just what possible ways there are to debug and fix this.
I know I shouldn't use Selection Sort / Insertion Sort for parallelizing, that I should use merge sort and quick sort with their parallel versions instead, but this is just for fun and to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a significant problem with how you launch your threads:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i <= rows; ++i)
>     {
>         InsertionSortPacking __tempPacking{};
> ```

Note that the lifetime of `__tempPacking` is one iteration of the host loop, yet here ...

> [...]
>
> ```
>         int __rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], nullptr, insertionSort, (void *)&__tempPacking);
> ```

... you pass a pointer to `__tempPacking` to the new thread.  Once that object's lifetime ends, the new thread must not attempt to access it, but even if all `insertionSort()` does with it is read the members back out into local variables, nothing forces that to complete within the object's lifetime.  This is a race condition in the general sense, even if not a "data race" in the sense defined by the language standard, and when the sort thread loses, the resulting behavior is undefined.

> ```
>         if (__rc)
>         {
>             std::cout << "[ERROR] Unable to create thread, rc " << __rc << " i, " << i << std::endl;
>             exit(-1);
>         }
>     }
> ```

You go on to remark

> 1. This does not seem like a race condition at all. Each array is different and independent in memory. No two threads access a different
>    thread anywhere in the sequence

See above.  There is indeed a race condition, just not with the objects you're looking at.

> 2. ... It could be that threads are sometimes joined when they are partially sorted - can that happen?

Since you have UB, anything can happen.  In the absence of UB, joining a thread causes the joiner to wait for the thread function to terminate.  You haven't presented it, so I can't speak to whether your `insertionSort()` function might be prone to terminating without fully sorting the array, but that would not be a characteristic specific to its use in a multi-threaded program.

> 3. I'm not running more threads than my machine can handle ( 4 cores for sure )

And that doesn't much matter.  You can have more threads than cores; they just won't all run concurrently.

> 4. I do not understand where to and how to debug why sometimes 1 thread fails, or why 3 threads fail the other time

Yes, debugging multithreaded programs can be very challenging.  Many debuggers can run multithreaded code and interrogate the states of different threads, but threading-related bugs are particularly likely to be sensitive to execution environment, such that they may not manifest when running in a debugger.

> 5. I do not see the need for mutex locks here at all. No race conditions, but maybe I'm thinking about this from the wrong angle

You can avoid use of synchronization objects by ensuring that the `InsertionSortPacking` object provided to each thread outlives that thread, while retaining the property that each thread gets its own, distinct one.

Alternatively, you could allocate those dynamically and give the sort threads responsibility for deleting them.

> 6. I tried using sleep() to make sure the threads get their work done in due time BEFORE joining them together, but to no avail.

Sometimes `sleep()` works around synchronization problems, but it is never a true solution.  If there is a race condition then `sleep()` can skew the likelihood for each competitor to win, but that doesn't fix the problem that there is a race in the first place.

In this case, a `sleep()` might actually prevent the issue from manifesting if you put it at the end of the thread-launching loop instead of after, but that would defeat your purpose, and again, it wouldn't be a genuine solution.

Comment: Very cool! Thank you for the answer. Let me try out with what you have said. And get back to you on this. I'll be sure to tick the answer if this thinking works out for me.

Comment: It was a race condition. Solved. Thank you!